# What's the default height of a blank View?

Tags: java, android

I want to separate the 4 icon  with equal space like `pic1`.

[image: pic1]

And the XML code for `pic1` is:

[image: code1]

However, at the first time, I set the Blank View height as `wrap_content`, then the result showed like this:

[image: pic2].

The code for `pic2` is:

[image: code2].

The only difference is highlight by red rectangle.

Comment: Please consider including code snippets directly, not via links, it is much harder to open all the links and compare the code. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in place of that linearlayout containing all the icons:

```
<LinearLayout
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--keep your first icon code here-->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--keep your second icon code here-->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--keep your third icon code here-->

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <!--keep your fourth icon code here-->

</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case of this layout, you will get more from a [`ConstraintLayout`](https://constraintlayout.com/).

Specifically, setting your icons within a `ConstraintLayout` would look like this to get the balanced look you're going for:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/check"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image_2"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/check"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_1"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image_3"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/check"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_2"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/image_4"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image_4"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/check"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toEndOf="@id/image_3"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"/>
</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

The takeaways from this snippet that get your look are:

- `horizontal` Orientation for the `ConstraintLayout`
- Constraints for each `ImageView` that attach them to the one before and after
- First view is constraint to the `parent`, specially, as is the last view
- `app:layout_constraintHorizontal_chainStyle="spread_inside"`, says to spread them out evenly within the available space.

If you don't want them touching the sides, add padding to the left/right of the parent `ConstraintLayout`.

Comment: I will try ConstraintLayout next time, thanks for your suggestion!